# JQuery .post() not working at latest version?

Tags: jquery

Something happen with later version of Jquery where it work fine with 1.4.1,1.4.2,1.4.4...
Below is the code that I tried.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" 
    type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Test post.php is a empty file with just opening of `<?php ?>`

```
$.post("testpost.php",function(data){
                        alert("Hello World");
                      });
```

Arghhhh I found the problem that was the button type where it couldn't be submit so instead of submit I changed to button and finally it works. Thanks everyone for your quick response.

Comment: what is an error .... or question ?

Comment: $.post() works just fine in jQuery 1.5.x . What's the problem? You don't reach the server? You don't get a response? The response is not what you expect?

Comment: I didn't get the response and no error tho.. > <

Comment: @Eric what was supposed to get as a response?

Comment: A very simple alert("Hello World"); As in the code written when success.

Comment: What data are you expecting back from the server? If you are passing back JSON data that isn't 100% properly formed (ie you run the response through JSLint and get errors) then JQuery 1.4 on will fail it (even though 1.3 will allow it). Try the code with the ajax function (with a defined error handler)as, per the api, the post is set up to fail silently.

Comment: in jQuery 1.5 their is a little thing more that in old version if code not match documentation then they work but 1.5.1 not allow them different  you need to do exact as the rule define in jQuery 1.5

Comment: If you solved it, post the answer. Don't make the edit in the question. You don't put [solved] in the title either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the `alert("Hello world")` is not displayed because you are not receiving any response from the server. The `function(data){...}` is only called on success.

Answer (score 1):

In the most recent distribution of jQuery, I've had much trouble for some reason doing `$.post()` without any `POST` parameters. Try using `$.get()` and see how that works out.

It's be helpful if you posted the HTTP response code you got from the `POST` request here (you can usually find that somewhere in your browser's Developer Console).

Answer (score 1):

The following thing clear here :-

1st: are you sure that you fire event after document ready [because it's work 1.4.2 or down version i am sure that's not a problem]

2nd : do a thing that change your code to

```
$.post("testpost.php",{},function(data){
                        alert("Hello World");
                      });
```

a issue in 1.5 is that in last and older version if they not match exactly then they work but in 1.5 it's a problem that whenever code is not matched and exact as documentation the problem maybe come.

Answer (score 1):

First check if `testpost.php` exists and the path is correct.

On what event is the `post request` sent? Try wrapping it inside `$(document).ready();`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post("testpost.php",function(data){
         alert("Hello World");
    });
});
```

Even if this also dont give you a response. Update your question with the code inside `testpost.php`.